# Saving the Dynamically Changed HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done some changes in HTML page dynamically by using jQuery. And if I reload the same HTML it will gets to its initial state. But i don't want that to happen. Is there any way to get it done or save the changes made using jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: When the page loads it loads the code you enter in html, and not the changes you made using jquery. You need to save the code changes and try :)

Comment: localStorage is also not permanent.You  need to use `ajax` and try to save changes permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Now its working fine. The problem was i didnt had the URL to make ajax call. Now I got it.

Comment: @AkshayPalekar next time post your code will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to make changes to a file using jQuery and load it back on the reload you need to use a database in order to save those changes. You can use AJAX or even pure JavaScript to transfer those changes from your form to the database.

And once the changes are saved you can use a combination of PHP, MySQL query and JavaScript or AJAX to dynamically load the changes from the database on to your HTML page or if you want to make it more simple then just use a JavaScript function on page reload to fire a PHP code which will check for changes and if there is any, those will be loaded on to your page.

HTML5 local storage is a temporary solution this will also get retested once you close your browser or clean the browsing data.

Comment: Edited the answer to broaden the scope and give you an idea about how to submit and then retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the innerHTML string and save it to the database or via HTML5 localStorage.

Then onload, all you have to do is check for an existing page state and then insert that as an innerHTML to your parent container:

```
if(savedState){
      myParentContainer.innerHTML = savedState;
}
```

Where savedState is the variable that holds your html code.

To save the state, you would need to design a save function that would fire every time changes are made or when the user clicks on a save button. As I have said, you can save via HTML5 LocalStorage or via a database. Be wary that HTML5 LocalStorage is very small and can only accommodate several megabytes.

Comment: localStorage is also not permanent.He  need to use `ajax` and try to save changes permanently

Comment: True, HTML5 LocalStorage only saves in the browser storage, so the event of clearing your browsing data or uninstalling it would permanently remove your local storage data. Database is still the best way

Comment: Thanks for your help . Now its working fine. The problem was i didnt had the URL to make ajax call. Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to save your HTML after made changes using Jquery. you could save it by ajax call and save into database. so when you reload page HTML fetches from database so it would work.